# Combing two regex expressions to keep escaped characters but exclude non-escaped characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For example, I have a string `"aout\>>>out\\nt\\<foo<<bar"`
I'm having trouble finding regex that would find words:

- `"aout\>"`
- `"out\\nt\\<foo"`
- `"bar"`

I am trying to exclude any '<' or '>' or '|' characters that are not escaped with '\'.

Right now, I have `[^ \t\n]+` to give me all "words" without <>|, but I want to exclude the part of the string that has the expression `(?:(?<!\\)[<>|])+` (any non-negated <>|). Is there a way to combine these two expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\\[<>|]|[^\s<>|])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZzKJr/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\\[<>|]` - a `\` char and then a `<`, `>` or `|` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\s<>|]` - any char other than a whitespace, `<`, `>` and `|`
- `)+` - end of the non-capturing group, one or more repetitions.